# ASP.NET behaving strangely with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to modify displays and checkboxes from asp.net controls using javascript, cuz the updatepanel is just pure rubbish. But for some absurd reason, this works:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_MainContainer_WorkContainer_AppointmentFormView_RecurringRow').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
```

and this does not:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_MainContainer_WorkContainer_AppointmentFormView_RecurringRow').style.display = 'none';
```

if i actually do it the second way, and i debug the value on display, it actually says none, but it's still visible in my UI. Weird stuff...

The same goes with the checked value, if I set this:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_MainContainer_WorkContainer_AppointmentFormView_Monday').checked = false;
```

it just doesn't work, the only work around for this is to see if the value is actually checked and then click it, like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_MainContainer_WorkContainer_AppointmentFormView_Monday').checked) {
                    document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_MainContainer_WorkContainer_AppointmentFormView_Monday').click();
                }
```

Any ideas of what i need to double check? because this is just not making any sense to me :)

Comment: Really nobody has any idea??

Answer (score -1):

change all the above like this

```
document.getElementById('<% AppointmentFormView_RecurringRow.ClientID %>').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
  document.getElementById('<% AppointmentFormView_RecurringRow.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('<% AppointmentFormView_Monday.ClientID %>').checked = false;
if(document.getElementById('<%AppointmentFormView_Monday.ClientID%>').checked) {
                document.getElementById('<%AppointmentFormView_Monday.ClientID%>').click();
            }
```

Comment: That's not the problem I am having, if i use the client id or the actual id, doesn't change a thing. I will still have the same problem. The problem is that first one works, second one doesn't, third one doesn't and fourth one does. But they should actually all work